# Remove cellspacing without border-collapse

Tags: css, border, spacing

I just stumbled upon this issue and i can't think of a solution

I have a table in which i want to have the table-rows a top and a bottom border in different colors.

If i simply do the following

```
table tr { border-top:solid 1px #201e1f;border-bottom:solid 1px black; }

[..]

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I get a spacing between all the cells (which makes sense) but when i add the following CSS line, the bottom border overrules the top border, so i only get to see one border

```
table { border-collapse:collapse; }
```

Does anyone know how i can get two *connecting* borders on my table rows?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "connecting" borders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like you're looking for [border-spacing](http://www.css4you.de/border-spacing.html).

Comment: Yep, that did the trick.
Don't work on a table-row though, only on table cells

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test, but try this:

```
cellspacing: 0
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_cellspacing.asp for more info. And don't collapse your borders.